# How to access to the previous URL parameters from router

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

suppose I have following structure:

http://localhost:4000/projects/:project_id/context_items/:ci_id

I have separate routers for projects and for context_items, but the problem is
when I am on context_items route I need to access project_id parameter, but it is not present in req.param.

When I set my routes I do following:

```
module.exports = (app)=>{
    app.param('project_id', (req, res, next, project_id)=>{
    console.error(project_id);
    next();
});

app.param('ci_id', (req, res, next, ci_id)=>{
    console.error(ci_id);
    next();
});

//Routes setting....

const projectsRouter = require("./client/projects");
app.use("/projects", projectsRouter)

const contextItemsRouter = require("./client/context_items");
app.use("/projects/:project_id/context_items", contextItemsRouter);

....
```

The project_id fires but ci_id misses.... I can just write a function and extract project_id from the base url, but what would be the proper way to access project_id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router

In short:

```
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true})
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it's exactly what I needed thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `GET` request in your `API` set up like:

```
app.get('/projects/:project_id/context_items/:ci_id', function(req, res) {})
```

You can acess both `project_id` and `ci_id` using `req.param`.

However, if you have a parameter middleware like:

```
app.param('[project_id', 'ci_id']', (req, res, next, value)=>{
  next();
});
```

You can bind anything you want to the request, e.g. `req.value = value`

Since the middleware runs before every route that matches either the `project_id` or the `ci_id` parameter, `req.value` value will change depending on your request.

So if your server gets this request: `GET /project/12/context_items/24` and your `API` has a route set up that logs the value of `req.param`:

```
app.get('/projects/:project_id/context_items/:ci_id', function(req, res) { 
  console.log(req.value)
 });
```

It will first log 12, then 24.

Comment: well, the problem is that context_items is a separate router which root is /projects/:project_id/context_items/   so my get requests there look like app.get('/:ci_id', (req, res)=>{//do stuff}); So I only have access to :ci_id... I was able to get :project_id in the index router, where I assign all other routers, but such approach seems wrong, as I have to gather parameters in many different routers... Ideally, is there a middleware that just get all the parameters an places them in the request?

Comment: Yes. You can get the value of more than one parameter by putting them in an array like app.param(['project_id', 'ci_id']). I will update my answer to clarify